# Removing Outliers Issue

Tags: r, outliers

I tried running this code to remove the outliers but two outliers still exist.

```r
newData <- read.csv(file = 'https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/f7ms-98xd.csv', header = T)
boxplot(newData$bachelor_s_degree)$out
no_outliers <- boxplot(newData$bachelor_s_degree)$out
print(no_outliers)
newData[which(newData$bachelor_s_degree %in% no_outliers),]
newData <- newData[-which(newData$bachelor_s_degree %in% no_outliers),]
boxplot(newData$bachelor_s_degree)
```

The picture shows the two variables that still exist after running the code.

[image]

I'm trying to remove all the outliers in the example but for some reason these two variables still exist. Is there one code that will remove all the variables?

Comment: I am voting to close because we do not have your data to replicate your issue. But I will leave this comment: removing so called "outliers" is an iterative issue. After you remove some of them - suddenly, when looking at the data, some other points might become "outliers". I think that is what is happening in your case.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius the data is being pulled from an online CSV. If you run the line of reading the csv, it should give you the data.

Comment: @AK, I just tried the link : https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/f7ms-%2098xd.csv and it gives : 'dataset missing' error. So! Also, Karolis is right about the outliers part. However, without the dataset, it would be difficult to help.

Comment: So my impression was wrong - the data is available. But there is a needless space after the dash. However your issue is that after removing the original "outliers" new "outliers" show up. If you don't want to have them just run your outlier removal procedure again. I am still voting to close, because this question is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you removed the outliers, you had:

```
IQR(newData$bachelor_s_degree)
[1] 265.25
median(newData$bachelor_s_degree)
[1] 127.5
```

So the outliers were those points greater than

```
median(newData$bachelor_s_degree) + 1.5 * IQR(newData$bachelor_s_degree)
[1] 525.375
```

After you remove the outliers,  both the median and the IQR change, so that:

```
median(newData$bachelor_s_degree)
[1] 121.5
IQR(newData$bachelor_s_degree)
[1] 249
median(newData$bachelor_s_degree) + 1.5 * IQR(newData$bachelor_s_degree)
[1] 495
```

Your data set has a few points outside the *new* outlier range, that is they are less than 525.375 (so they were not removed the first time) but greater than 495 (so they count as outliers now).